# ISP Refusing more IP addresses, want to run VM servers

Tags: ip, virtual-machines

I have some great servers that are really underutilized and would love to setup about 20 VM servers but my ISP won't give me any more addresses. I currently have 5, and while they keep saying they will do it, nobody ever follows through and it has been about 6 months going back and forth. I need to find a simple way around the problem if possible.

I know about Nginx and HAProxy, though I have yet to implement it as it seemed more complicated that it should be. I don't want to forward just 1 or 2 ports, but ALL ports based off the incoming hostname request. When I or someone else is setting up a project, I don't want them to have to wonder if the problem is in the port forwarding or in the iptables of the server.

I have looked at this project on and off for months trying to use everything from an F5, PfSense and OpnSense. This doesn't seem like that strange of a request to me, with the prominence of virtual servers, it seems there has to be a simple solution at the firewall / gateway level to split the traffic up to a bunch of local ip addresses. In each case it seemed the solution was either poorly documented, or limited in scope to a single port at a time.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you thought about using IPv6 for your vm's ?

Comment: Honestly I don't know anything about it more than it is a replacement for IPv4, wouldn't I still need to get those assigned by the ISP though?

Comment: In many places, there just aren't any IPv4 addresses to be had. You could be waiting a long time. And you should have implemented IPv6 years ago. Now you're going to have to play catch up.

Comment: The problem isn't that they don't have them. It is a small town ISP. We had agreed to build them a website in exchange for hosting, after we were about $10K into the project, they backed out. Since then communication and follow through seems to just die off once we are out of sight, so I am trying to make the best of what we have.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to cut your losses and move to a competent (and predictable) hosting provider.

Comment: I would if there was any other option in the area, this is the only provider other than Comcast that does fiber and we get a great deal on a 100MB upload, which is something Comcast wouldn't do since they top off with 20MB upload.

Comment: @Alan No, I meant that you should stop self-hosting and use a remote hosting provider.

Comment: @EEAA Amen brother. Anything that doesn't absolutely need to be on premise shouldn't be on premise.

Comment: Agreed, I do have about 10 servers in datacenters, but at the office I have development boxes, small appliances such as an SMS box and such. I typically stage things in office, then when all is ready I put it in a datacenter. I like to try out new technologies like ESXI and get them stable before putting my server somewhere it is a pain to get to :)

Comment: Wait, Comcast? You should already be getting IPv6 there. Contact them to find out what's going on. You might need a new cable modem or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many internal IPs as you want, so I would recommend the VMs all use IPs in and internal network like 192.168.X.X or 10.X.X.X. Then have your limited external IPs on your gateway device (typically a firewall). On that firewall you can setup NAT to forward the public address to a private one. This of course is a problem in your case because you don't have enough public addresses to do a straight 1 to 1 translation. You have a couple options:

1) PAT - Port Address Translation

This will work for services for which you have control of both ends. eg. SSH/RDP. You configure IP A port 22 to go to VM1 and then other ports to go to the rest of the VMs. port 2222 to VM2, 2223 to VM3 etc. For administration this is fine. This does not work for incoming public connections on standard ports (eg. HTTP. For these you want option 2)

2) Reverse Proxy

You mention HAProxy and NGINX above. Both of these can be configured to do reverse proxy. You set up one VM with a public IP on it and point all DNS to that. Then configure the proxy to forward requests to the correct destination server based on some criteria (in your request you mention using incoming hostname).

Here are instructions for those daemons (And a bonus for apache):

- https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/
- https://seanmcgary.com/posts/haproxy---route-by-domain-name
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

The reason standard firewalls can't do what you want is because they only operate at Layer 3 and don't have any knowledge of the hostname or URL requested.